# adapter doesnt change when list is changed in kotlin

Tags: android, adapter, android-livedata

I have a list and an adapter, I get the list from the service and when it arrives, I give it to the adapter with `submitlist`. When I make a `submitlist`, the list appears properly, but when it goes to the adapter, it appears empty. I couldn't find the reason, can you help me? here are my codes

**ProfileStatisticAdapter**

```
class ProfileStatisticAdapter(
    private val salesRange: List<String>?,
    private val itemClickListener: ((Int) -> Unit)? = null
) : ListAdapter<String, ProfileStatisticAdapter.StatisticViewHolder>(StatisticDiffCallback) {

    private val salesOptions = listOf(
        "last 1 day sale",
        "lasy 7 day sale" ,
        "last 30 day sale"
    )

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Log.d("ProfileStatistics salesRangeLiveData","salesRange value: "+salesRange)
        return salesRange?.size ?: 0
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = StatisticViewHolder(
        ItemStatisticSellingBinding.inflate(parent.context.inflater, parent, false)
    )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: StatisticViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(position)
    }

    inner class StatisticViewHolder(
        private val binding: ItemStatisticSellingBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(position: Int) = with(binding) {
            val salesValue = salesRange?.get(position)
            tvSalesReport.text = salesOptions[position]
            tvSalesPrice.text = salesValue.orEmpty()
            root.setOnClickListener { itemClickListener?.invoke(bindingAdapterPosition) }
        }
    }

    object StatisticDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<String>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

> Log.d("ProfileStatistics salesRangeLiveData","salesRange value:
> "+salesRange) -> salesRange value: []

**ProfileStatisticsActivity**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ProfileStatisticsActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
     private val binding by viewBinding(ActivityProfileStatisticsBinding::inflate)

    private val viewModel: ProfileStatisticsViewModel by viewModels()

    private val statisticAdapter: ProfileStatisticAdapter by lazy {
        ProfileStatisticAdapter(emptyList())
    }
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        collectState(viewModel.uiState) { renderView(it) } ...
     
 private fun renderView(uiState: StatisticsUiState) = with(binding) {

        viewModel.userLiveData.value.apply {
            tvUserName.text = this?.userName.orEmpty()
        }

        statisticAdapter.submitList(uiState.salesRange)
        statisticAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

`statisticAdapter.submitList(uiState.salesRange)` The **uiState.salesRange** value here is null at first, then it is filled with data from the service.

**Viewmodel:**

```
     private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(StatisticsUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<StatisticsUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

init {
        userLiveData.value?.id?.let {
            fetchStatistics(it)
        }
    }

  private fun fetchStatistics(userId: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            runCatching { fetchStatistics.invoke(userId) }
                .onSuccess {statistics ->
                    _uiState.update {
                        it.copy(
                            salesRange = statistics.sales?.range
                        )
                    }
                    userStatisticsLiveData.value = statistics
                    salesRangeLiveData.value = statistics.sales?.range
                }.onFailure { showError(it) }

        }
    }
```

**UiState:**

```
data class StatisticsUiState(
    val userStatistics: StatisticsResponse?= null,
    val salesRange: List<String>? = null
)
```

Comment: Can I see your `submitList` method?

Comment: Did you check your `renderView` method? Is it triggering? I think `collectState` is a custom method. If `renderView` is not triggering can I see the `collectState` method?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

**ProfileStatisticAdapter**

```
class ProfileStatisticAdapter(
) : ListAdapter<String, ProfileStatisticAdapter.StatisticViewHolder>(StatisticDiffCallback) {

    var salesRange = listOf<Float>() 
    ...
  @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun updateItems(salesRange: List<Float>) {
        if (salesRange != this.salesRange) {
            this.salesRange = salesRange
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
    ...
```

**Activity:**

```
 statisticAdapter.updateItems(userStatistics.sales?.range.orEmpty())
```

I solved this problem like above. I declared default list in ProfileStatisticAdapter and added update function and handle from activity.